# Classification of closures of additive subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

If $G$ is an additive subgroup of the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{G}$ is the topological closure of $G$ then either

- $\overline{G} = a \cdot \mathbb{Z}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, or
- $\overline{G} = \mathbb{R}$.

If instead $G$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is there a classification of the the possible values of the topological closure $\overline{G}$ of $G$?

What if $G$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: I have seen the $n$-dimensional case cited as being in Bourbaki's *General Topology VII*, §1, Theorem 2, but haven't verified. For the other case I do not know, but [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45322/closed-connected-additive-subgroups-of-the-hilbert-space) makes it seem like the infinite-dimensional case can be quite different.

Comment: It's a question about closed subgroups of these various groups. Yes, for $n$ finite: the closed subgroups are indeed the images under $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ of the subgroups $\mathbf{R}^k\times\mathbf{Z}^\ell\times\{0\}^m$ for $k+\ell+m=n$.

Comment: I can confirm that this the reference of @Mark is correct (maybe slightly more specifically it's VII, §1.2, Theorem 2).