# Is $L^2(I,\mathbb Z)$ homeomorphic to the Hilbert space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, hilbert-spaces, examples

I am somehow puzzled by the subset $G:=L^2(I,\mathbb Z)$ of $H:=L^2(I,\mathbb R)$ of all integer valued functions on $I=[0,1]$ (in fact I mentioned as an example in [this old MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45322/closed-connected-additive-subgroups-of-the-hilbert-space)).

Some simple observations: it is a complete metric topological additive group, though of course not a linear subspace; it is connected (even by $1/2$-Hölder arcs); it is contractible, via the homotopy $G\times[0,1]\ni(f,s)\mapsto h(f,s):=f\chi_{[0,s]}\in G$. And then, what else can be said?

> Is it homeomorphic to the whole space $H$? Is there an explicit
> homeomorphism?

Comment: What would happen, if we compare $L^2(I,\{0,1\})$ with $L^2(I,\mathbb{R})$? I dont know if these spaces are homeomorphic.

Comment: The paths in the upper homotopy decrease the distances to $0$. Thus $\varepsilon$-Balls are contractible and hence $L^2(I,\mathbb{Z})$ is also locally contractible.